# Javascript Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript

i've a div with an id that encoded with base64 encryption.
it looks like this:

```
<div id="tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q=">
```

and when im trying to delete it by using the id like that:

```
$('div[id=tagValue_tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q=]').remove();
```

im getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[id=tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q=]
```

but when i remove the " = " from the encryption it works:

```
<div id="tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q">
```

it will work with the code:

```
$('div[id=tagValue_tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q]').remove();
```

how can i make it work and also leave the " = " ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select ids as such:

```
$('#tagValue_tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q\\=').remove();
```

instead of trying to grab it as an attribute.  Your earlier problem was due to the equals sign being syntactically significant.  You can avoid this by quoting in the attribute selector:

```
$('div[id="tagValue_tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q="]').remove();
```

Comment: works like a charm. thanks! i can't believe i didnt think about that

Comment: The `=` will [need to be escaped](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in the ID selector -- `$('#tagValue_tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q\\=')`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
$('div[id="tagValue_tagValue_16DXp9eR15Q="]').remove();
```

? Just don't forget that string is a string ;o)